# failed to load an image when converting html to pdf with pandoc

Tags: pdf, pandoc

I use jekyll to generate html files having an image like:

`<img src="/assets/images/view.png" alt="" />`

When I generate a PDF with pandoc with that HTML, it shows:

`Warning: Failed to load file:///assets/images/view.png (ignore)`

The resulting PDF doesn't contain the image.

I think that's because the image's path is absolute, it loads from the file system, absolute path. I have tried `--resource-path=assets/images/` but doesn't help. Does anyone know how to load images successfully under this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a simpler solution, but I'd solve this by using a Lua filter that fixes the image path:

```lua
function Image (img)
  -- remove leading slash from image paths
  img.src = img.src:gsub('^/', '')
  return img
end
```

Save this to a file `fix-img.lua` and pass the file to pandoc via the `--lua-filter` option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `img.src:gsub('^/', '')` works for me.